# How to convert cell array of string numbers into numerical vector

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I am using Matlab and I have the following data:

```
a = {'3' '11' '7'}; % This is what I have.
```

My goal is to use a function to convert such cell into a vector having the following shape:

```
b = [3 11 7]; % What I need to get!
```

If I try to use the `b = cell2mat(a)` function the result that I get is this number: `b = 3117;` which is not what I want.

What function should I use to reach my goal? If possible please do not use for loops but just Matlab functions.

Comment: `b =str2double(a)` - if there is a String Type in your Cell a, it will return a NaN. Please read our Matlab Documentation - there is a section in the Intro I wrote specifically on this.

Comment: @excaza help loop -->

loop not found.

Comment: @excaza your comments are less useful than the manual and yeah... loop is not a function in Matlab yet... get over it... if you don't give constructive comments you should consider giving up this site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [**`str2double`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html):

```
b = str2double(a);
```